# Angular: Using selected file for image preview

Tags: angular

As part of our application we would like to preview the files the users are uploading, before they are actually available on the server. To do this I have tried a couple of things:

- Assigning the file directly to the background-image style attribute. (Both with url() and without)
- Generating a blob using `URL.createObjectURL()`, gives `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value blob:http://localhost:4200/16db9654-3119-4d55-9b59-715c2d31b334 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

  - Adding `url()` around the blob url: `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url(blob:http://localhost:4200/86da46b1-5431-46d0-8757-13c75e09abc2) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`
- Sanitizing the the blob url directly using the DomSanitizer `ERROR Error: Required a safe Style, got a URL`

  - Adding `url()` around the sanitized value in the template `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url(SafeValue must use [property]=binding: blob:http://localhost:4200/72561f3d-0ff7-435b-8ac9-ec3a7c0cfbb0 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`
  - Adding `url()` around the blob url before sanitizing `ERROR Error: Required a safe Style, got a URL`

And during none of these the background image actually appeared. I checked the dom using the chrome inspecter, and in none of the cases did the attribute actually get set.

So what is the correct way of doing this? I have a File instance at start.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want user A to upload a file to server and user A should be able to preview that file prior to uploading?

Comment: That is indeed what I would like to be able to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type='file' (change)="onAdd($event)">

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" *ngIf="url">
    <img [src]="url">
</div>
```

Type Script:

```
onAdd(event: any) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.slika = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT:

Change your code to this:

```
public addFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.url = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
  }
```

and this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="addFile($event)">
```

With these changes it should work now.

Comment: I might not have made it completely clear, I would like to use to image for a background-image, not as a src for img.

Comment: @Rasmus Hansen can you paste piece of code where you want your image to show, so I can see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rasmus Hansen I have checked your stackblitz and I have posted changed code above.

Comment: Ohh, so URL.createObjectURL can't actually be used for that? That's sad :(, but ohh well, this works, thats enough for me :D

Comment: @Rasmus Hansen Try `console.log(event.target.files[0])` and `console.log(this.url)` You will notice the difference. FileReadre creates a string in memory containing a base64 representation of the image, while CreateObjectUrl creates a url for the specified blob.

Comment: Yeah, i got that much. I was trying to avoid keeping the entire image in memory, but I guess if i'm previewing it, then it doesn't matter that I have to keep a base64 version around too. (We sometimes deal with some quite large images)

Comment: @RasmusHansen have you found out large image file preview with ease? sometime DOM hangs on large image file previewing..

Comment: @GaurangDhorda We pass them through a canvas to resize them. However if they are too big, we just skip previewing them entirely until the backend has generated a smaller preview.